# In SystemVerilog - What's the difference between "tran" and "alias"?

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to connect to bi-directional ports and I saw there are 2 solutions for this. `tran` primitive and `alias` statement. However, I don't understand the difference between them.

```
module tran_mod (i, o);
  inout i, o;
  tran (i,o);
endmodule

module alias_mod (a, b);
   inout a, b;
   alias a = b;
endmodule
```

What is the difference between module "tran_mod" and "alias_mod"?

Comment: you have to provide an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I've edited my original question to include the code snippets I am trying to discern between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Verilog `tran` primitive models a switch-level device between two 1-bit nets. The actual algorithm is not defined in the LRM but events on one net schedule events on the other connected net. Also, the `tran` primitive cannot pass supply strength across its terminals.

SystemVerilog added the `alias` construct which is a more complete bus symbolic renaming capability. It can handle packed arrays and concatenations of nets.

There is actually a third way of connecting bidirectional ports using module port expressions. But there is no need to go into that since the other two methods can handle everything as well.

Answer (score 1):

`tran` is a *bidirectional pass switch*. It is used in transistor/switch level modeling. It connects two *different physical nets*. It describes *hardware*.

`alias` is a System Verilog behavioral construct which declares that two or more different net names refer to the *same physical net*. It describes *behavior*.

On the top in simple cases both statements can *behave* similarly. But the rest depends on your other requirements.